# How do I ls a directory to get it's data, but none of its files?

Tags: ls

I wish to run ls -alh on a directory, so that I can get when the directory was last modified.

I do NOT want to get the ls information for the files in that directory, just that directory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Turn's out it's easy

```
ls -alhd
```

The -d flag reports on directories, not their files